# Replacing nulls in rows with a default value in a SQL pivot query

Tags: sql-server

Using a SQL Server 2016 database I use this code:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        u.firstname AS 'first name',
        u.lastname AS 'last name',
        gi.idnumber AS 'examcode',
        gg.finalgrade AS 'grade'
    FROM mdl_grade_grades gg
    INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id
    INNER JOIN mdl_user u ON gg.userid = u.id
    WHERE gi.idnumber IN ('148','414','413','228','359','379','398','104','351','436','434','384','385','377','280','395')
    AND gg.userid = '62750'
) SOURCE
PIVOT (
    MAX(grade)
    FOR examcode IN ([148],[414],[413],[228],[359],[379],[398],[104],[351],[436],[434],[384],[385],[377],[280],[395])
) PIVT
ORDER BY 'last name', 'first name'
```

to produce a pivoted list of scores for various gi.examcodes.
If there is no record (row) for a specific gi.examcode the SQL Server database returns a NULL, like this:

```
first name  last name    148    413    228    359    379    398     104    351    436    434    384    385    377    280    395
John        Brown        94     96     97     NULL   NULL   NULL    100    NULL   NULL   94     86     83     85     93     NULL
```

When written to an html page the table shows empty values where there are NULLS. How can I replace the NULLs that are returned with a generic value, like this:

```
first name  last name    148    413    228    359    379    398     104    351    436    434    384    385    377    280    395
John        Brown        94     96     97     None   None   None    100    None   None   94     86     83     85     93     None
```

Comment: Well what code is rendering the HTML? Can't that code just say if a value is `null` put `None` instead? To use `COALESCE([359], 'None')` you're going to have to change from `PIVOT` to either dynamic `PIVOT` or `MAX(CASE`.

Comment: No, I can't do the "null to none" conversion on the html side.

Comment: @luisdev, can you expand on why that's not possible? This will not fit into any i18n your web page might be using....

Comment: I wasn't using any html. I wanted to run the query to produce a .csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much better to deal with presentation issues like this at the presentation layer. However, if you can't, you'll have to change your query, since `PIVOT` doesn't support expressions directly. Some options:

Option #1 - nest the `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT [first name], [last name], 
  [148] = COALESCE([148],'None'), [414] = COALESCE([414],'None'),
  [413] = COALESCE([413],'None'), [228] = COALESCE([228],'None'),
  [359] = COALESCE([359],'None'), [379] = COALESCE([379],'None'),
  [398] = COALESCE([398],'None'), [104] = COALESCE([104],'None'),
  [351] = COALESCE([351],'None'), [436] = COALESCE([436],'None'),
  [434] = COALESCE([434],'None'), [384] = COALESCE([384],'None'),
  [385] = COALESCE([385],'None'), [377] = COALESCE([377],'None'),
  [280] = COALESCE([280],'None'), [395] = COALESCE([395],'None')
FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      u.firstname AS [first name],
      u.lastname AS [last name],
      gi.idnumber AS [examcode],
      CONVERT(varchar(11), gg.finalgrade) AS grade -- if grade is actually numeric
    FROM dbo.mdl_grade_grades gg
    INNER JOIN dbo.mdl_grade_items gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.mdl_user u ON gg.userid = u.id
    WHERE gi.idnumber IN ('148','414','413','228','359','379','398','104',
                          '351','436','434','384','385','377','280','395')
    AND gg.userid = '62750'
  ) SOURCE
  PIVOT (
      MAX(grade)
      FOR examcode IN ([148],[414],[413],[228],[359],[379],[398],[104],
                       [351],[436],[434],[384],[385],[377],[280],[395])
  ) PIVT
) x
ORDER BY [last name], [first name];
```

Option #2 - `MAX(CASE`:

```
SELECT [first name] = firstname, [last name] = lastname,
 [148] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '148' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [414] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '414' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [413] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '413' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [228] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '228' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [359] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '359' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [379] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '379' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [398] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '398' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [104] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '104' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [351] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '351' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [436] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '436' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [434] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '434' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [384] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '384' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [385] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '385' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [377] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '377' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [280] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '280' THEN grade END), 'None'),
 [395] = COALESCE(MAX(CASE idnumber WHEN '395' THEN grade END), 'None')
FROM 
(
  SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, gi.idnumber, 
    grade = CONVERT(varchar(11), gg.finalgrade)
  FROM dbo.mdl_grade_grades AS gg
  INNER JOIN dbo.mdl_grade_items AS gi 
    ON gg.itemid = gi.id
  INNER JOIN dbo.mdl_user AS u 
    ON gg.userid = u.id
  WHERE gi.idnumber IN ('148','414','413','228','359','379','398','104',
                        '351','436','434','384','385','377','280','395')
  AND gg.userid = '62750'
) AS x
GROUP BY lastname, firstname
ORDER BY lastname, firstname;
```

Option #3 - dynamic SQL - much more flexible for adding/removing courses, only specifying the list of courses once, and maybe easier/harder to read depending on the reader.

```
DECLARE @userid varchar(11) = '62750', @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT 
  [first name] = firstname, 
  [last name]  = lastname';

CREATE TABLE #g(i int IDENTITY(1,1), id varchar(4));

INSERT #g VALUES ('148'),('414'),('413'),('228'),('359'),('379'),('398'),('104'),
                 ('351'),('436'),('434'),('384'),('385'),('377'),('280'),('395');

SELECT @sql += N',
  ' + QUOTENAME(id) + N' = COALESCE(MAX(CASE i WHEN ''' 
  + id + ''' THEN grade END),''None'')'
FROM #g ORDER BY i;

SET @sql += N'
FROM 
(
  SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, gi.idnumber AS i, 
    grade = CONVERT(varchar(11), gg.finalgrade)
  FROM dbo.mdl_grade_grades AS gg
  INNER JOIN dbo.mdl_grade_items AS gi 
    ON gg.itemid = gi.id
  INNER JOIN dbo.mdl_user AS u 
    ON gg.userid = u.id
  INNER JOIN #g AS g
    ON g.id = gi.idnumber
  WHERE gg.userid = @userid
) AS x
GROUP BY lastname, firstname
ORDER BY lastname, firstname;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@userid varchar(11)', @userid;

DROP TABLE #g;
```

There are plenty of ways to do this, but they're all going to be either ugly or unintuitive (and sometimes both). This is because T-SQL isn't meant for prettifying presentation - that's what HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and other client-side technologies are for. Also, you should store numbers as numbers and treat them as numbers. And [always use semi-colons](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons), [always use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix), and don't use `AS 'last name'` - much safer to use `AS [last name]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the splat in your outer select, address each field and handle the null.

```
SELECT 
    [first name]
    , [last name]
    , [examcode]
    ,isnull([148], 0) as [148]
    ,isnull([414], 0) as [414]
    ,isnull([413], 0) as [413]
    ,isnull([228], 0) as [228]
    ,isnull([359], 0) as [359]
    ,isnull([379], 0) as [379]
    ,isnull([398], 0) as [398]
    ,isnull([104], 0) as [104]
    ,isnull([351], 0) as [351]
    ,isnull([436], 0) as [436]
    ,isnull([434], 0) as [434]
    ,isnull([384], 0) as [384]
    ,isnull([385], 0) as [385]
    ,isnull([377], 0) as [377]
    ,isnull([280], 0) as [280]
    ,isnull([395], 0) as [395]
 FROM (
    SELECT
        u.firstname AS 'first name',
        u.lastname AS 'last name',
        gi.idnumber AS 'examcode',
        gg.finalgrade AS 'grade'
    FROM mdl_grade_grades gg
    INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id
    INNER JOIN mdl_user u ON gg.userid = u.id
    WHERE gi.idnumber IN ('148','414','413','228','359','379','398','104','351','436','434','384','385','377','280','395')
    AND gg.userid = '62750'
) SOURCE
PIVOT (
    MAX(grade)
    FOR examcode IN ([148],[414],[413],[228],[359],[379],[398],[104],[351],[436],[434],[384],[385],[377],[280],[395])
) PIVT
ORDER BY 'last name', 'first name'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option is creating a subset of possible combinations via a CROSS JOIN, and then within the PIVOT, we do a UNION ALL

**Example**

```
;with cte0 as (
    SELECT
        u.firstname AS [first name],
        u.lastname AS [last name],
        gi.idnumber AS [examcode],
        convert(varchar(50),gg.finalgrade) AS [grade]   
    FROM mdl_grade_grades gg
    INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON gg.itemid = gi.id
    INNER JOIN mdl_user u ON gg.userid = u.id
    WHERE gi.idnumber IN ('148','414','413','228','359','379','398','104','351','436','434','384','385','377','280','395')
    AND gg.userid = '62750'
),cte1 as (
    Select [first name],[last name],examcode,grade
     From (Select Distinct [first name],[last name] from cte0 ) A
     Cross Join (Select Distinct examcode,grade='None' from cte0) B
)
Select *
 From (
        Select * from cte0
        Union All
        Select * from cte1
      ) src
 Pivot (
        max(grade)
        for examcode IN ([148],[414],[413],[228],[359],[379],[398],[104],[351],[436],[434],[384],[385],[377],[280],[395])
       ) pvt
 ORDER BY [last name], [first name]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your current query a CTE or derived table, and SELECT from it using ISNULL().